# Parallel memory duplication/usage in R?

Tags: r, memory, foreach, parallel-processing

I have written a program to generate a very large amount of random multivariate distributed data **(25 x 30 x 10 000 000)** using `mvtnorm`, then do some simple calculations and manipulations on the matrices.

I am using the `foreach` and `doParallel` packages to run operations in parallel to reduce time. A completely arbitrary example, just to demonstrate the packages is:

```
foreach (x = matr) %dopar% {
    x[time_horizon + 1] <- x[time_horizon]
    x <- cbind(100,x)
    for (m in 2:(time_horizon + 1)) {
      # loop through each row of matrix to apply function
      x[,m] <- x[,m-1] + x[,m]
    }
    return(x)
  }
```

I have created an implicit cluster of cores to run these `foreach` functions on:

```
registerDoParallel(4)
```

**The problem**

When I run with multiple cores, it appears to multiply or duplicate the memory used when I monitor performance on Task Manager (i.e. 2 cores uses more memory than 1 core, 4 cores uses more memory than 2).

When I run my program for **(25 x 30 x 1 000 000)**, running in parallel helps the speed of execution (i.e. 4 cores is faster than 1 core). However, when I run my program for **(25 x 30 x 2 500 000)** and above, too much memory is used and that appears to slow it down.

One friend said it could potentially be a page fault and the hard drive must be accessed when I run out of RAM.

Why is the duplication of memory across cores happening? Is it supposed to happen? Can I stop it? Are there other solutions?

**Edit (Full Code):**

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

# Calculate the number of cores
no_cores <- detectCores()

# Create an implicit cluster and regular cluster
registerDoParallel(no_cores)

daily_pnl <- function() {
  time_horizon <- 30
  paths <- 2500000
  asset <- 25
  path_split <- 100

  corr_mat <- diag(asset)
  expected_returns <- runif(asset,0.0, 0.25)

  # Create a list of vectors to store pnl information for each asset

  foreach(icount(time_horizon), .packages = "mvtnorm") %dopar% {
    average_matrix <- matrix(, (paths/path_split), asset)
    split_start <- 1
    my_day <- rmvnorm(paths, expected_returns, corr_mat, method="chol")
    for (n in 1:(paths/path_split)) {
      average_matrix[n,] <- colMeans(my_day[split_start:(split_start + path_split - 1),])
      split_start <- split_start + path_split
    }
    return(average_matrix)
  }
}

matrix_splitter <- function(matr) {
  time_horizon <- 30
  paths <- 2500000
  path_split <- 100
  asset <- 25

  alply(array(unlist(daily), c(paths/path_split,time_horizon,asset)),3)
}

cum_returns <- function(matr) {
  time_horizon <- 30
  paths <- 2500000
  asset <- 25

  foreach (x = matr) %dopar% {
    x[time_horizon + 1] <- x[time_horizon]
    x <- cbind(100,x)
    for (m in 2:(time_horizon + 1)) {
      # loop through each row of matrix to apply function
      x[,m] <- x[,m-1] + x[,m]
    }
    return(x)
  }
}

plotting <- function(path_matr) {
  security_paths <- as.data.frame(t(path_matr))
  security_paths$id <- 1:nrow(security_paths)
  plot_paths <- melt(security_paths, id.var="id")

  ggplot(plot_paths, aes(x=id, y=value,group=variable,colour=variable)) +
    geom_line(aes(lty=variable))

}

system.time(daily <- daily_pnl())
system.time(daily_by_security <- matrix_splitter(daily))
rm(daily)
gc()
system.time(security_paths <- cum_returns(daily_by_security))
rm(daily_by_security)
gc()

plot_list <- foreach(x = security_paths, .packages = c("reshape2", "ggplot2")) %dopar% {
  if (nrow(x) > 100) {
    plotting(head(x,100))
  } else {
    plotting(x)
  }
}

#Stop implicit cluster and regular cluster
stopImplicitCluster()

gc()
```

Comment: Why are you surprised that each core needs memory for its tasks?

Comment: @Roland I just thought all 4 cores would use the same amount of memory in total as 1 core because they are creating the same amount of data and doing the same things that 1 core would do. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Yes, this is incorrect. If one core needs memory for a task, four cores need four times the memory to do it in parallel. Then you have the memory needed by the parent process to manage parallelization and to hold the results.

Comment: @Roland Thank you. So is the reason this takes longer when there's too much memory a page fault? Does it need to access the hard drive when it runs out of RAM? When I'm monitoring on Task Manager, it appears that when it maxes out, CPU usage suddenly drops from 90+% to ~0%. Then the RAM usage decreases gradually and linearly, while CPU usage rises again gradually.

Comment: I can't say more without a reproducible example. Different operating systems will handle this differently. (Memory issues restricted me once from using 64 cores to only using 8 cores.)

Comment: @Roland Thanks Roland! I've just added the full reproducible example to the question.

Comment: You create a matrix of 2.5 million values within each task. You can estimate how much memory this matrix alone needs for storing it in each task. And you need also memory to work with it. But what the OS does if you run out of RAM depends on the OS and the relevant settings. Your system might swap which results in a huge slowdown if you don't use an SSD for this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a really old problem. I am having a similar issue. I don't need compute parallelization I actually need memory parallelization. (if such a thing can exist)

what works for me is azure do parallel. instead of registering system cores register cores from the cloud using `registerDoAzureParallel(cluster)`

your json will define the size of the machines (memory) you hire for the job. make sure each worker has enough memory to get a copy of your r environment. This will probably kill your network. You will be sending data to 30 -40 (depending on how many you have asked for) workers from your machine.

more documentation here.
https://github.com/Azure/doAzureParallel

Can we do something with sparklyr to address such issues?